# How to hide text in Word Document using Apache POI library

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

Is it possible to hide text in MS Word Document using Apache POI library? If yes, please let me know how. I am able to create and read the document using POI library. Is there any way to hide some kind of text (could be in header or anywhere in the document).

Thanks in advance,

idds24

Comment: When you say "hide" you mean present in the document a user could open, but hidden somehow? If so, that's a Word question.  Please clarify your question to say which Word technique you want to use to hide it.  The question is then how to do it in POI.  Are you working with binary doc or zipped xml docx?

Comment: @JasonPlutext: By "Hide" I meant it is present in the doc. I want it for my further operation while importing that doc while creating it. I want to know how could I make a text hidden using POI in MS Doc. I am currently working with binary doc. But would like to extend it docx as well.

Comment: You can use hidden text; see http://www.microsoft.com/education/en-us/teachers/how-to/Pages/hidden-text.aspx 

There are other techniques for associating data with the document which keep it off the document surface.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: I want it to be automated, through my code using POI (or any open source library in java). Can it be done in automated way?

Comment: Can what be done in an automated way?  Do you mean add hidden text as described in the link above, or something else?

Comment: The link explains how to do it manually. I mean, selecting the text and assigning it with hidden property. I want this same functionality to be done using some API for my Java code.

Comment: I can tell you how to do it for a docx, using docx4j, if you are interested. For binary doc, you need an answer from someone familiar with HWPF, either here or on the POI mailing list.

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Yes, please tell me how to do it in docx. I also want it in doc as i am currently working on doc. However, docx will also be helpful.